# Not nullable types

Tags: c#

Is there a way to create a non nullable type in C# (like DateTime or TimeSpan).?

Also is there a way (an attribute maybe) to enforce that not null arguments wouldn't be passed to methods and properties without adding

```
if(arg1 == null)
{
   throw new ArgumentNullException("this attribute is null")
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`DateTime` and `TimeSpan` are not-nullable since they are `struct`s rather than `class`es.

As for your second question, there is no standard way you can do this in C#. You can do this using PostSharp, which is an AOP framework, or with [Spec#](http://research.microsoft.com/SpecSharp), which is a whole new language (an extension of C#) which allows for some of desired behavior.

Comment: If you are using a post-build step, then there absolutely is a standard way to do it: Code Contracts is officially part of .NET 4 (and available separately for .NET 3.5).

Answer (score 11):

The null-checking you refer to will be easier in .NET 4.0 / C# 4.0 via code-contracts, which does pretty much what you want.

Structs are already non-nullable, but don't go creating your own structs like crazy - you rarely need them (classes are **far** more common). There is no real concept of a "non-nullable class"; people have *proposed* syntax changes like:

```
void Foo(string! arg1) {...}
```

which would have the compiler do the non-null check on `arg1` - but in reality, code-contracts does this and more. There are some things you can do in PostSharp, but it probably isn't worth the hastle.

One other thought on a non-nullable class (and one of the reasons they aren't implemented); what would `default(T)` be for a non-nullable class? ;-p The spec *demands* that `default(T)` is well defined...

Comment: The difference between the new syntax proposal and code contracts is that the above can be *statically* checked.

Comment: For those reading this now, Code Contracts now implements static checking.

Comment: `string!` is in Spec#.

Answer (score 6):

A non-nullable type is a ValueType, in other words a struct. A struct cannot be null, so an example would be:

```
public struct MyStruct {}
```

There is no built-in way of ensuring that null is not passed as a parameter to a method (unless the type of the parameter is a ValueType). I have seen people create extension methods for doing a simpler (ie. less code) assertions on whether a parameter is null, this might be an option for you. On the other hand, the check is short to begin with; and the intent of the check is very clear. That might not be the case if you use a custom method of checking.

C# 4.0 will add better options for doing this kind of programming by contract, but is not available yet. As pointed out in another answer [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.org/) is an option for doing what you want. PostSharp works by adding a post-compilation step where extra code is added.

There are some options for statically checking whether null might be passed, however. For example, ReSharper lets you decorate your own method parameters with a  [NotNull] attribute, and ReSharper will issue warnings at compile time if it can determine that the parameter might be null. Of course this only warns you about (potentially) bad coding practice, it is not a runtime check and should not be used as such.

Answer (score 4):

You are right: this is a shortcoming in C# compared to C++. This is a shame, because 95% of all parameters I pass to functions are non-null pointers. In C++, you can add compiler-checked documentation indicating which pointers are ensured to point to something.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the AOP solutions mentioned, Enterprise Library offers this in their validation block.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff953182(v=pandp.50).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Structs (value type) variables will never be null - that explains your DateTime case. So if your method params are C# structs, you can be sure they will never be null.
However if your method params are reference types, they can be null. I dont think you can do away with the null check as you've shown above in that case.

Answer (score 1):

As for the second question, here is an idea inspired by `Nullable<T>`.

A method with null-checked arguments would look like:

```
void Foo(NotNull<string> s)
{
    var x = $"{s}";
    var i = int.Parse(s);
}
```

Usage of `NotNull<T>` isn't limited to method arguments. And it would be certainly nice if the language has some syntactic sugar for it in the future, e.g. `Foo(string! s)`.

```
public struct NotNull<T> where T : class
{
    private T valueField;

    public NotNull(T value)
    {
        this.valueField = value;
        this.CheckNotNull(value);
    }

    public T Value => this.valueField;

    public static implicit operator T(NotNull<T> t)
    {
        return t.Value;
    }

    public static implicit operator NotNull<T>(T t)
    {
        return new NotNull<T>(t);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object other)
    {
        return this.Value.Equals(other);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return this.Value.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.Value.ToString();
    }

    private void CheckNotNull(T value)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"Value cannot be null");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

YES! C# 8.0 introduced non-nullable reference types: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references

```
string message = null;

// warning: dereference null.
Console.WriteLine($"The length of the message is {message.Length}");

var originalMessage = message;
message = "Hello, World!";

// No warning. Analysis determined "message" is not null.
Console.WriteLine($"The length of the message is {message.Length}");

// warning!
Console.WriteLine(originalMessage.Length);
```

This is enabled by default on new projects. If you update the .NET version of an existing project, this won't be automatically enabled, but you can enable it in `Project -> Properties -> Nullable`.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can write your own value types (`enum` and `struct`) which can't be null (unless made nullable).

As for the second part, you can have a generic parameter and a constraint of accepting only value types, which means argument can not be null - not very useful considering vast majority of cases we use `class`.

```
public static void Do<T>(T arg1) where T : struct
{
    //both struct and enum goes here.
}
```