# Is there a way to require that an argument provided to a method is not null?

Tags: c#, null, methods, arguments

Is there a better way to require that an argument is not null in a method? I keep checking if any of the arguments that my method requires are null, as show below. But I'm wondering if there is a better way.

```
public void MyMethod(string a, int b)
{
   if(a==null){throw new ArgumentNullException("a");}
   if(b==null){throw new ArgumentNullException("b");}

   //more stuff here
}
```

Comment: This is an almost exact duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/718630/not-nullable-types

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rick Brewster (author of Paint.NET) blogged about a Fluent API alternative:

http://blog.getpaint.net/2008/12/06/a-fluent-approach-to-c-parameter-validation/

Answer (score 2):

You can write some utility methods. This is the common pattern in java.

user code:

```
public void MyMethod(string a, int b)
{
    //validate each
    Objects.RequireNotNull(a);
    Objects.RequireNotNull(b);

    //or validate in single line as array 
    Objects.RequireNotNullArray(a, b);
}
```

implementation code:

```
public static class Objects
{
    public static T RequireNotNull<T>(T arg)
    {
        if(arg == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }
        return arg;
    }

    public static object[] RequireNotNullArray(params object[] args)
    {
        return RequireNotNullArray<object>(args);
    }

    public static T[] RequireNotNullArray<T>(params T[] args)
    {
        Objects.RequireNotNull(args);
        for(int i=0; i<args.Length; i++)
        {
            T arg = args[i];
            if(arg == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException($"null entry at position:{i}");
            }
        }
        return args;
    }

}
```

You cannot get the variable name in the exception. but with the stack trace and your source code, it should be possible to easily track down.

Answer (score 1):

There is no other better way. This is the way a ton of Microsoft libraries handle the situation.

You can always use an extension method to make it a little clearer.

```
static IsNullArgument(this Object o, string arg)
{
    if (o == null)
        throw ArgumentNullException(arg);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I personally like [CuttingEdge.Conditions](http://www.codeplex.com/conditions).  It's easy to use, and makes this much more readable.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the few areas where I think C# went backwards from C++.

In C++, you could write

```
void foo(Bar& bar) { /*...*/ }
```

to quite clearly indicate to both the compiler and other humans that `foo` took an actual instance of `Bar`.  Yes, it is possible--with effort--to pass `foo` a null reference but that's not really legal C++.

Your only "solution" (of sorts) in C# is to make your `class`es `struct`s instead, as value types in .NET can't be `null` (in your example, *b* can't ever be `null` because it is a `System.Int32`).  The call to `bar()` will not compile:

```
    class A { }
    struct B { }

    static void foo(A a) { }
    static void bar(B b) { }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        foo(null);
        bar(null);
    }
```

It certainly seems like it would have been nice for C# to have made it (much) more difficult to have `null` references; F#, for example, has no nullable types.

For some interesting commentary related to this matter, read [Null References: The Billion Dollar Mistake](http://sadekdrobi.com/2008/12/22/null-references-the-billion-dollar-mistake/) (and the comments).

---

**Edit:** A February 2013 footnote from [Eric Lippert](http://ericlippert.com/2013/02/25/monads-part-two/) says "... it just so happened that when C# was first implemented it had always-nullable reference types, ... it seems plausible that `Nullable<T>` could have been implemented to work on any type, and reference types would then be non-nullable by default. We could have a type system where `Nullable<string>` was the only legal way to represent "a string that can be `null`". ... "