# C# .NET: Is it possible to create compile time warnings when property is set to invalid values?

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

This is just a feasibility question.  I know that if I say

```
   int myInt = "5";
```

I get a compile time error.  What I want to do is create compile time errors or warnings on objects. So let's say I have a custom object with a few properties.  One of the properties cannot be null otherwise the solution will not compile:

```
   public static class NoNullObjects
   {
       //NotNullable
       public static NotNullObject {get; set;}
   }
```

MyClass.cs:

```
   Line#55   NoNullObjects.NotNullObject = null;
```

When I build I want to see:

```
   Error: NotNullObject cannot be set to null. MyClass.cs Line 55.
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: See [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/718630/not-nullable-types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/718630/not-nullable-types)

Comment: This does not solve the OP's question. As the OP requests non nullable reference types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, not with just C#.  Microsoft's Code Contracts work may give you what you want: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/dd491992.aspx.

Comment: I'll just have to wait for .NET 4 then :)  Why is what I want to do always in the next iteration?

Comment: Nate: You can always download the VS2010 beta which has .NET 4.0.

Comment: I used to be big into design by contract, now I'm big into unit testing.  From my experience, unit testing is enormously more effective then using asserts / code contracts.  I recommend getting into unit testing rather then waiting for code contracts.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337673/how-do-i-enforce-null-checking/2337709#2337709) is a question that covers the same topic. The accepted answer suggests that you use [code contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/dd491992.aspx).